# dispatchEvent not working with KeyboardEvents (Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to listen for the down arrow key and fire a tab event in its place.

My template contains this

```
<li #elRef 
    *ngFor="let handler of clickHandlers"
    (click)="doClickHandlerAction(handler)"
    (keydown)="checkArrowKey($event, elRef)">
```

And my component contains the following

```
checkArrowKey(event: KeyboardEvent, el) {
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
      event.preventDefault();

      let keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        "code": "9",
      });

      el.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 9) {
      console.log("tab key pressed");
    }
  }
```

When the down arrow key is pressed it dispatches the event but the element does not seem to receive the event. The if statement at the bottom checks if the tab key was pressed but this does not get called after the event was dispatched.

Interestingly, if I replace the keyboardEvent with a MouseEvent such as the following

```
let clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
```

My doClickHandlerAction() function will get called, indicating that the problem is with the KeyboardEvent.

Comment: The solution I went with instead involved checking if the element was last in the list by using the ngFor last variable and if it is not last call el.nextSibling.focus()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that `(keydown)` event work on focusable elements only such as `input` and `textarea` so add `tabindex="0"` attribute on `li` to add the focus behavior:

```
<li #elRef 
    *ngFor="let handler of [1,2,3]" 
    (keydown)="checkArrowKey($event, elRef)" tabindex="0"> hh </li>
```

also when you dispatch an event the `keyCode` value become `0`, so use `event.code` to read the key code :

```
checkArrowKey(event: KeyboardEvent, el) {

    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
      event.preventDefault();

      let keyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        "code": "9",
      });

      el.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 9 || event.code === '9') {
      console.log("tab key pressed");
    }
  }
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atkcxv)

Comment: That explains why it wasn't printing out the "tab key pressed" message which answers my question. I was hoping that I could simulate the tab key being pressed using this method so that the arrow key would behave like the tab key but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Argument of type '{ code: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEventInit'.